# How to overturned array result tree from child-parent to parent-child in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anyone help me with javascript function to get overturned of this following array. This result I got from database and intends to do some tree using javascript.

```
[{
    SubCategoryId: 1,
    SubCategoryName: "SubCategoryName1",
    Category: {
        CategoryId: 11,
        CategoryName: "CategoryName1",
        MainCategory: {
            MainCategoryId: 111,
            MainCategoryName: "MainCategoryName1",
        }
    }
},{
    SubCategoryId: 2,
    SubCategoryName: "SubCategoryName2",
    Category: {
        CategoryId: 11,
        CategoryName: "CategoryName1",
        MainCategory: {
            MainCategoryId: 111,
            MainCategoryName: "MainCategoryName1",
        }
    }
},{
    SubCategoryId: 3,
    SubCategoryName: "SubCategoryName3",
    Category: {
        CategoryId: 22,
        CategoryName: "CategoryName2",
        MainCategory: {
            MainCategoryId: 111,
            MainCategoryName: "MainCategoryName1",
        }
    }
}]
```

The result i was expected is :

```
[{
    MainCategoryId: 111,
    MainCategoryName: "MainCategoryName1",
    Category: [{
        CategoryId: 11,
        CategoryName: "CategoryName1",
        SubCategory: [{
            SubCategoryId: 1,
            SubCategoryName: "SubCategoryName1",
        }, {
            SubCategoryId: 2,
            SubCategoryName: "SubCategoryName2",
        }]
    }, {
        CategoryId: 22,
        CategoryName: "CategoryName2",
        SubCategory: [{
            SubCategoryId: 3,
            SubCategoryName: "SubCategoryName3",
        }]
    }],
}]
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: The structure is from child-parent, I need to change it to parent-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function category (arr) {

    // Start with empty array
    ret = new Array();

    // Iterate arr
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        // Search MainCategory
        var match = false;
        var j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < ret.length; j++) {
            if (ret[j].MainCategoryId == arr[i].Category.MainCategory.MainCategoryId) { match = true; break; }
        }

        // If not exist MainCategory
        if (!match) {
            ret.push({
                MainCategoryId: arr[i].Category.MainCategory.MainCategoryId,
                MainCategoryName: arr[i].Category.MainCategory.MainCategoryName,
                Category: []
            });
        }

        // Search Category
        match = false;
        var k = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < ret[j].Category.length; k++) {
            if (ret[j].Category[k].CategoryId == arr[i].Category.CategoryId) { match = true; break; }
        }

        // If not exist Category
        if (!match) {
            ret[j].Category.push({
                CategoryId: arr[i].Category.CategoryId,
                CategoryName: arr[i].Category.CategoryName,
                SubCategory: []
            });
        }

        // Insert Subcategory
        ret[j].Category[k].SubCategory.push({
            SubCategoryId: arr[i].SubCategoryId,
            SubCategoryName: arr[i].SubCategoryName
        });

    }

    // Return new array
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This is great!! and work as well, thanks a lot, really appreciated.